# TextBlock takes too much vertical space

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I have simple control consisting from button, image inside, and TextBlock. The problem is, that TextBlock takes some extra space on top of actual text, which visually screws some of my margins (especially between image and text).
Here is picture with TextBlock selected in Snoop.
[image: Problematic TextBlock]

Here is style for TextBlock used:

```
<Style x:Key="ManagerNameStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5, 0, 5, 3"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
    <Setter Property="Text" Value="Patients"/>
</Style>
```

Empty project with created TextBlock using this style also has same space.

[image: Simple text]

So, can i somehow remove this space? Could it be reserved for some specific symbols?

Comment: Can we see also `style` or settings of button with image?

Comment: It is not related to question. You can reproduce this with style I've provided on any TextBlock.

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with the TextBlock and not with its containing element?

Comment: See updated description. Empty project with text block alone has same space on top.

Answer (score 0):

Play with the **Padding property**.

```
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="10, 4, 5, 3"/>
```

If not **negativ margins** could be the solution.